# Calculate conversion rate in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

The code below calculates the conversion rate of a dataset. The code relevant to this question is in line 13. When I calculate the conversion rate, I divide the total number of purchases made on the website by the total number of users (people who browse) on the website. The output I get is 0.495 but I don't understand why I need the '1.0 *' at the start of line 13 for this to work? I don't know the purpose of this part of the code, but without it the code doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Post code as formatted text, not as a pictiure.

Comment: may be for data type conversion.

Comment: *why I need the '1.0 *' at the start of line 13 for this to work?* Without it the calculations will be integer ones whereas with it they're real

Comment: MySql does not perform integer division between integers, so 1.0 is not needed there.

Comment: But your code does not look like mySql, rather it looks like SQL Server. So you need 1.0

Comment: Or maybe SQLite? Tag the correct database that you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not MySQL code.  MySQL does not support square braces around identifiers.  One database that does is SQL Server.  And it does integer division.  So, in SQL Server, `1/2` is `0` rather than `0.5`.

The `* 1.0` simply converts the integer to something with a decimal point.

Assuming `userid` is not `NULL`, this is more easily expressed as:

```
avg( is_purchase * 1.0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

[forpas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10498828/forpas) and [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) are correct that SQL Server performs integer division by default. In future, and for more complex calculations, you can use CTEs or subqueries employing CAST to represent values as floating point values prior to division. E.g., at lines 6-7 you would have:

```
CAST(p.userid IS NOT NULL AS float) AS is_purchase
```